# Can a person be hypnotized to act drunk?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, hypnosis

I was wondering if a person could be hypnotized to act drunk? That is, can a person totally lose all his inhibitions while in hypnosis (similar to being drunk)?

Answer (score -2):

**Yes** ([video example of Derren Brown making a man drunk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=js_unuMakWc)) with caveats:

1. Not for every person being drunk means loosing his inhibitions
2. You can't force people to do something they don't want to do ([example by Anthony
   Galie](https://youtu.be/gygL_CXAZk0?t=16m27s))

Comment: And is this Derren Brown reputable?

Comment: @AliceD very. But in fact he already demonstrated, more than once that **it is possible** to make people do something against their "will" so to speak - by convincing them they were in fact doing something else.

Comment: @Marc.2377 - Derren Brown is a stage hypnotist.  Everything he does is staged.  As you pointed out, you cannot force somebody to do something against their will.

Comment: @ChrisRogers is it really so?

Comment: @Marc.2377 Links to state you cannot be forced to do something against your will 1. [Psychology Today](https://www.psychologytoday.com/gb/blog/hypnosis-the-power-trance/201509/is-total-mind-control-possible) 2. [Australian Government](https://www.betterhealth.vic.gov.au/health/ConditionsAndTreatments/hypnosis).  If you think it's ok in the first place you can be made to do it under hypnosis.  If you don't want to, you can't.

Comment: @ChrisRogers Thanks, but I meant to question if is it really true that _everything_ Derren Brown does is staged. Regarding hypnosis' ability to "force" someone to do something they normally wouldn't, have you seen the [Assassin Experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owootTAuxic)? In this demonstration, Brown trains someone to shoot at a person by making the subject see a shooting target instead of an actual person. I find that very credible.

Comment: @ChrisRogers You can't use hypnosis to force someone to eat an onion, but if you make the subject to really think the onion is actually an apple, it's doable.

Comment: The question doesn't assume forcing.